# Nginx is inner or outer Docker

Tags: nginx, docker

When I read some articles about Nginx and Docker. I know that Nginx is a web-server and it's work is to get request from client and contribute request to specific application inner machine.
Docker is a container that can contain my application inner it. It can contains a lot of things, like db, web application. It can install some packages like a Unix machine.
My question is when configure Nginx used for Docker application. We will install Nginx inner Docker or inner our machine(ubuntu or Centos...)?

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to run Nginx in its own container, where you publish the ports to the host, so when a request comes in to port 80 on the host, Docker will direct it to the Nginx container to process it.

All the other parts of your app (web front end, API, database, cache etc.) all run in their own containers, and Nginx is the proxy for anything that needs to be externally available.

Main advantages to this approach:

- you build all your Nginx configuration into a Docker image, so you can run that anywhere, you don't need to copy conf files around;
- you have minimal dependencies on your host - when you add a new machine or replace it, you only need to install Docker and then run all your containers;
- your app containers don't need to be publicly visible - if you run Nginx on the host, then to proxy your apps they would need to publish their ports to the host. By running everything in containers in a Docker network, the apps don't need to publish their ports, e.g. port 5000 in an app container is available to the Nginx container, but not on the host.

Comment: Publishing ports to the host doesn’t make it public though, right? Your firewall still blocks those from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

NGINX will exist inside the docker container. You will open port 80 in the container to allow the host machine to make HTTP requests to NGINX inside the docker container.

You might want to use the official NGINX docker container inside your dockerfile.

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Your dockerfile will have ...

FROM NGINX (at the top)

EXPOSE 80 (http)

EXPOSE 443 (https)

Then when you run the docker container use the -P (capital P) flag to make both exposed ports available to the host machine.

Comment: port 80 is inner Docker. But user request is sent to our machine.(CentOS, ubuntu...). How can our machine route that request to Docker without NginX?

Comment: you need a web server like NGINX - docker just contains the webserver ... you can map ports when running the container by -p 1245:80 - then access port 1245 on the host machine to hit NGINX inside the container

Answer (score 0):

It can be on both. In terms of scalability, I will choose in a self docker container. This way, you can grow differently your frontend and web server (or reverse proxy), and get the benefits of a dockerized version (put in another instance and/or server, go to cloud, etc.)